# Ubuntu 16.04 hybrid GPU

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, hybrid-graphics, gpu-driver

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) on my workstation with 3 monitors, 2 monitors run through a Radeon HD 7450 with no problems and the 3rd runs through the onboard Intel integrated gpu.

This was all working fine a few weeks ago, until I noticed the common cursor corruption glitch when using certain programs and attempted to fix it. In the course of fixing the cursor glitch I think I managed to remove some graphic drivers which has now stopped the Intel integrated gpu from functioning (though I did manage to fix the cursor glitch).

How can I get my 3rd monitor working again, ideally without the mouse cursor corruption glitch?

```
➤ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos PRO [Radeon HD 7450]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7c20000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Thanks!